# Docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/root/.gitconfig': mkdir /host_mnt/root: operation not permitted

Tags: docker, github, composer-php, devops

For the past 2 days I have been trying to run github action locally using the act tool.

My action looks like this:

```
name: stan
on: [push]

jobs:
  stan:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: php-actions/composer@v6
        with:
          args: --ignore-platform-reqs

      - name: PHPStan Static Analysis
        uses: php-actions/phpstan@v3
        with:
          path: src/ tests/
          configuration: phpstan.neon
          memory_limit: 1G
```

After performing operations in the terminal:
`act -j stan -s GITHUB_TOKEN=github...`

```
WARN  ⚠ You are using Apple M1 chip and you have not specified container architecture, you might encounter issues while running act. If so, try running it with '--container-architecture linux/amd64'. ⚠  
[stan/stan]   Start image=catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest
[stan/stan]     docker pull image=catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest platform= username= forcePull=true
[stan/stan]     docker create image=catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest platform= entrypoint=["tail" "-f" "/dev/null"] cmd=[]
[stan/stan]     docker run image=catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest platform= entrypoint=["tail" "-f" "/dev/null"] cmd=[]
[stan/stan]   ☁  git clone 'https://github.com/php-actions/composer' # ref=v6
[stan/stan] ⭐ Run Pre php-actions/composer@v6
[stan/stan]   ✅  Success - Pre php-actions/composer@v6
[stan/stan]   ☁  git clone 'https://github.com/php-actions/phpstan' # ref=v3
[stan/stan] ⭐ Run Pre PHPStan Static Analysis
[stan/stan]   ✅  Success - Pre PHPStan Static Analysis
[stan/stan] ⭐ Run Main actions/checkout@v3
[stan/stan]     docker cp src=/Users/pietrzakadrian/MyProject/. dst=/Users/pietrzakadrian/MyProject
[stan/stan]   ✅  Success - Main actions/checkout@v3
[stan/stan] ⭐ Run Main php-actions/composer@v6
[stan/stan]     docker cp src=/Users/pietrzakadrian/.cache/act/php-actions-composer@v6/ dst=/var/run/act/actions/php-actions-composer@v6/
[stan/stan] ⭐ Run Main set -e
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php-actions/php-build/cee5b9fa9fbc4c888e7a62bbb7b8eade18e3c56b/php-build.bash) composer
/var/run/act/actions/php-actions-composer@v6/composer-action.bash
[stan/stan]     docker exec cmd=[bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail /var/run/act/workflow/1-composite-composer_run.sh] user= workdir=
| Building PHP latest with extensions:  ...
| docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/root/.gitconfig': mkdir /host_mnt/root: operation not permitted.
[stan/stan]   ❌  Failure - Main set -e
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php-actions/php-build/cee5b9fa9fbc4c888e7a62bbb7b8eade18e3c56b/php-build.bash) composer
/var/run/act/actions/php-actions-composer@v6/composer-action.bash
[stan/stan]   ⚙  ::set-output:: name=full_command::composer install --no-progress --no-interaction --ignore-platform-reqs
[stan/stan] exitcode '125': failure
[stan/stan]   ⚙  ::set-output:: full_command=
[stan/stan]   ❌  Failure - Main php-actions/composer@v6
[stan/stan]   ⚙  ::set-output:: name=full_command::composer install --no-progress --no-interaction --ignore-platform-reqs
[stan/stan] exitcode '125': failure
[stan/stan] ⭐ Run Post php-actions/composer@v6
[stan/stan]     docker cp src=/Users/pietrzakadrian/.cache/act/php-actions-composer@v6/ dst=/var/run/act/actions/php-actions-composer@v6/
[stan/stan]   ✅  Success - Post php-actions/composer@v6
[stan/stan]   Job failed
Error: Job 'stan' failed
```

My docker has full disk access and shares the `/root/.gitconfig` and `/root/.ssh` folders. This action works on github.

Comment: not sure if this is related to the issue you are having but, the first line in the image says:
"You are using Apple M1 chip and you have not specified container architecture, you might encounter issues while running act. If so, try running it with '--container-architecture linux/amd64'. "

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:composer-php], but does not contain any such information?